# Conditional types over discriminant union

Tags: typescript

```
type A = { type: "x", x: number } | { type: "y", y: number };

1.

type B<T, K> = T extends {type:K} ? T : never;

declare function f<K>(k: K, p: B<A, K>);


f("x", { type:"y", y: 3 }); //no error


2.
type B<T, K> = T extends {type:K} ? Identity<T> : never;

type Identity<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };

f("x", { type:"y", y: 3 }); //error
```

What is difference between two cases, why does typescript infer different types for K in f in these two cases?

Comment: Ugh, the interplay between conditional type resolution/deferral and function parameter inference = .  This feels like a compiler bug or design limitation but I'm really not sure yet.

Comment: Okay, my *guess* here is that something about the simpler type signature (1) is causing `K` to be inferred from *both* the type of `k` *and* the `type` property of `p`, and you get a union.  TypeScript doesn't have a way to say ["don't infer from this site"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) but there's a way to say ["infer from this site later"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731), by intersecting the type parameter with `{}`, so `function f<K>(k: K, p: Extract<A, { type: K & {} }>) { }` should work as you want.

Comment: If someone comes up with something better (like, *why* the inference is happening that way) they should feel free to answer.  Otherwise I might turn this into a real answer once I get to an appropriate keyboard.

Comment: @jcalz I would go for regression, there is no error on 3.3: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeVSQFxQEQA8sBoodMA7AVwFsAjCAJygF8oAfZVcCTLEAqEUyjXoMA3ACgJaaACEAPABVCAaQB8CKPKgQcwCCQAmAZ2RT0SpgH4oASX17gAS1AK1pCADc64sVJt2Sjs7yaogoANpKUA4kUADWECAA9gBmGgC6mPIRaYzedgDGADYAhrTQyWQk+Y6JMcmyqgAUsZhKhGCYcjDKKgCUmO6JDvreyY24vCim3Lz8UADMjL0iUAD0q4mxUBYAhEA

Comment: You *want* an error, right?  You are passing in the wrong `p` for a given `k`.  It's There's definitely a change from [3.3](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeVSQFxQEQA8sG4odMA7AVwFsAjCAJygF8oAfZVcCTLEAqEUyjXoN8AKFFpoAIQA8AFQA0UANIA+BFDlQIOYBBIATAM5tJmZYygB+TVFIQAbnTGiDEAMYAbAIa1oAMzISd2AASwB7Eih-GQsdPUMTI2BaUJIAc1UACgBrcyUwTFkYJTUASkwHcNCDF38s3CwlFDNsHiV+KABmRjLCUSA) ...

Comment: ... to [3.4](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=type%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22x%22%3B%20x%3A%20number%20%7D%20%7C%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22y%22%3B%20y%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20B%3CT%2C%20K%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20%7B%20type%3A%20K%20%7D%20%3F%20T%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20f%3CK%20extends%20string%3E(k%3A%20K%2C%20p%3A%20B%3CA%2C%20K%3E)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Af(%22x%22%2C%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22y%22%2C%20y%3A%203%20%7D)%3B%20%0D%0A), though.

Comment: `declare var x:B<A,"x">; ` for first case works like for second with inferred type `{type:"x", x:number}`